# Pixel where top and left borders meet

Tags: html, css, border

I have a div that has a one pixel solid white border on the left and right, and on the top i have two pixel solid black border. On the corner where these borders meet, the pixel is showing up as white. Is it possible to make it black?

How does that work?

html:

```
 <div id="bodyholder"> 
  <div id="leftholder">
  Welcome to the website.... <br>
  <br style="line-height:10px">
  <img src="images/1_p1.jpg" align="left" style="margin-right:19px" alt="" border="0">
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor.               <br>
  <br style="line-height:40px">
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque           laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi           architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia.                             
  </div>
 <div id="middleholder">
 <img src="images/p1.png" alt="Statistics"/>
 <img src="images/p2.png" alt="Schoolwork"/>
 <img src="images/p3.png" alt="In the News"/>
 </div>
  <div id="rightholder">
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque      laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae.<br>
  <br style="line-height:10px">
  <img src="images/1_p1.jpg" align="left" style="margin-right:19px" alt="" border="0">
  <br>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque.<br>
  <br style="line-height:40px">
  Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil      molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? quis      nostrum exercitationem ullam vel eum iure reprehenderi.                            
  </div>
     <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerinner">                                             
     <div class="vlinks">vel eum iure reprehenderi</div>
        </div>
     </div>



  </div> 
  </div> 

  </body>
  </html>
```

and the css:

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-image: url(images/background.gif);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-position: center top;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Verdana;
color:#FFFFFF;
line-height:14px;
vertical-align:top;

 }
 #top{
 width: 766px;  

 }

 #fullholder{
margin: 0 auto;
width:766px;
height:100%;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #fff;
background-color: #000;

 }
 #nav{
background-color: #000;
height:84px;
 }

 ul#list-nav {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
width:764px;
height: 84px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-top: 0px;
 }

 ul#list-nav li {
display:inline;

 }

 ul#list-nav li a {
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font:24px "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
line-height:78px;
text-align:center
list-style-type:none;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
width:125px;
background:#b99757;
color:#FFFFFF;
float:left;
text-align:center;
border:1px solid #fff;
 }

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
background:#a2abb2;
color:#000
}

#list-nav #menu_active a{
 background:#a2abb2;
 color:#000;
 }


 #bodyholder{
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-color: #fff;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #fff;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000;
margin-left:2px;
width:760px;
height:470px;
background-image: url(images/1_bg.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
 }

 #leftholder{
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
border:10px solid #A2ABB2;
padding:10px 20px;
background:#000000;
width:215px;
height:354px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;    
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
display:block;
 }

 #middleholder
 {
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 8px;   
width:191px;
height:354px;   
display:block;
 }

 #rightholder{
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 1px;
border:10px solid #A2ABB2;
padding:10px 20px;
background:#000000;
width:215px;
height:354px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;    
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
display:block;
 }

 #rightholdertwo{
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 1px;
border:10px solid #A2ABB2;
padding:10px 20px;
background:#000000;
width:215px;
height:354px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;    
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
display:block;
 }
 #leftholdertwo{
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
border:10px solid #A2ABB2;
padding:10px 20px;
background:#000000;
width:215px;
height:354px;
border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;    
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
display:block;
 }

 #footer{
width: 760px;
background-color:#000000;
height: 55px;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:14px;


 } 
 #footerinner{
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
width: 734px;
height: 28px;
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:14px;
background-color: #A2ABB2;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top:11px;
color: #000;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey now you can used `after` properties

as like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">hello</div>
```

**Css**

```
body{
background:green;
}
.parent{
background:red;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px auto;
    position:relative;

}
.parent:after{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  top:-2px;
  background:#000;
  height:2px;
}
```

**Live demo** http://tinkerbin.com/UoyGDDqS